# histogram, bars in x axis cant be seen

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to do the following plot, the plot is an histogram with several bars for two groups.

[image]

My approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
graph2 |>
  filter(!is.na(healthy)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = total_visits, fill = as.factor(healthy))) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count))),
                 alpha = 0.6, color = "white", position = 'identity',
                 breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 10)) +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("TSCI", "SHS"), values = c("blue", "red")) +
  labs(fill = "")
```

The dataset is a bit huge but I add a sample with just 200 rows:

```
graph2 <- structure(list(total_visits_SHS = structure(c(4, 2, NA, NA, 2, 
                                              4, 6, 3, 3, 1, 12, NA, 3, NA, 12, 2, 2, 1, 2, NA, NA, 12, 3, 
                                              8, 3, NA, 1, 1, NA, 4, NA, 6, NA, NA, 2, 5, NA, NA, 15, 10, NA, 
                                              51, NA, 3, NA, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2, 8, 12, 50, 1, 4, 2, 2, 30, NA, 
                                              16, 2, 10, NA, 2, 5, 1, NA, 10, 3, NA, 24, 1, 7, 10, 5, NA, 10, 
                                              2, 1, 20, 1, NA, 1, 2, 1, NA, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 20, 6, 11, 4, 1, 
                                              4, 2, 5, 24, 8, 2, NA, NA, 2, 1, 12, 30, NA, NA, 10, NA, 3, 1, 
                                              4, 2, NA, 6, NA, 7, 50, 60, NA, 1, 1, 6, 7, NA, 4, 2, NA, 6, 
                                              NA, 3, 3, 4, 10, 1, 6, 5, NA, 10, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, 3, 12, 40, 
                                              1, 3, 6, 4, 3, 1, 2, 24, NA, NA, NA, 10, 12, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
                                              3, 18, 1, 4, 8, 4, 15, 4, 2, NA, 3, 20, NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, 2, 
                                              2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, NA, NA, 16, 1, 1, 7, NA), label = "number of medical consultation (last 12 months)", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
               healthy = structure(c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, NA, 0, 
                                     0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
                                     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
                                     0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                     1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
                                     0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                                     1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                                     1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
                                     1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
                                     1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), label = "Has no health condition", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
               total_visits_SCI = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                              NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), label = "SwiSCI - Total healthcare vistis", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
               total_visits = c(4, 2, 0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 3, 3, 1, 12, 0, 3, 
                                0, 12, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 12, 3, 8, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 6, 
                                0, 0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 15, 10, 0, 51, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2, 
                                8, 12, 50, 1, 4, 2, 2, 30, 0, 16, 2, 10, 0, 2, 5, 1, 0, 10, 
                                3, 0, 24, 1, 7, 10, 5, 0, 10, 2, 1, 20, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 
                                3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 20, 6, 11, 4, 1, 4, 2, 5, 24, 8, 2, 0, 0, 
                                2, 1, 12, 30, 0, 0, 10, 0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0, 6, 0, 7, 50, 60, 
                                0, 1, 1, 6, 7, 0, 4, 2, 0, 6, 0, 3, 3, 4, 10, 1, 6, 5, 0, 
                                10, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 12, 40, 1, 3, 6, 4, 3, 1, 2, 24, 0, 
                                0, 0, 10, 12, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 18, 1, 4, 8, 4, 15, 4, 
                                2, 0, 3, 20, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 16, 
                                1, 1, 7, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -200L), label = "TEL17_CH", class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                      "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

How to see better the values in x axis, specially the high values, in the plot generated by ggplot the bars are not seen. The plot that I created I made with all the data.

Comment: Try the following: (1) What is your max value for `total_visits` in the data? If it's much less than 100, by setting the x-axis to run from 0-100, you might be making it harder to see points. (2) bin values differently. In the plot you show first, values are binned by 2; in your plot they are binned by 1. Try `breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 2)` or increase beyond 2.

Comment: You could also try to plot without `color="white"` since very small columns appear completely white in your figure and it makes them difficult to distinguish from the white grid lines.

Comment: The typical way to do this would be to use a logarithmic y axis. Try adding `+ scale_y_log10()`

Comment: Also, you might want to use `limits = c(0L, max(graph2$total_visits)` inside `scale_x_sth()`.  Furthermore, the orginial plot corresponds to setting `expand = c(0L, 0L)` in both `scale_y_sth()` and `scale_x_sth()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to break y-axis in such kind of situations where the distribution of values are unclear, values are of different order of magnitude. It is something like zooming-in to better visualize low frequency values as in your dataset. One package that can deal with breaking axis is [ggbreak](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggbreak/index.html) and you can find more details in its tutorial. In your case I played with y values and found best in the range between (0.04, 0.1). The function is *`updated by adding a line before the last statement`*:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbreak)

graph2 |> filter(!is.na(healthy))|>
  ggplot(aes(x=total_visits,fill=as.factor(healthy)))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count))),
                 alpha=0.6,color="white", position = 'identity',
                 breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 1))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 10))+
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("TSCI", "SHS"), values = c("blue", "red"))+
  scale_y_break(c(0.04 , 0.1), scales = .5) +  theme_minimal() +
  labs(fill="")
```

Here is the output but you may play with break points as you prefer.

[image]

or breaking y-axis between (0.04, 0.05):
[image]

Also the function `scale_y_cut()` is another alternative from the package for adjusting the space parameter between sub-plots:

```
graph2 |> filter(!is.na(healthy))|>
  ggplot(aes(x=total_visits,fill=as.factor(healthy)))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count))),
                 alpha=0.6,color="white", position = 'identity',
                 breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 1))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 10))+
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("TSCI", "SHS"), values = c("blue", "red"))+
  scale_y_cut(c(0.04)) +  theme_minimal() +
  labs(fill="")
```

[image]